# Ajax web application framework

Tags: ajax, frameworks, web

I'm about to start a new web application project and am looking for advice about what technologies to use and how.

I've used ASP.NET webforms in my previous work, but this time I want to use Ajax to prevent the continual need for postbacks which would not suit the complexity of this application.

Essentially, the UI will have an interface similar to a traditional Windows application, for example a main view which will occupy the browser window and numerous modal dialogs which I'll display over the main view.

I suspect this will lead to a hugely complex and difficult to maintain application unless I'm able to componentize the project and load these components dynamically. For example, load the dialog HTML and script dynamically, on demand.

Is there an Ajax / web application framework out there that would support me in this approach? I'm most comfortable with ASP.NET so an approach centred around that would be preferable.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you may have a look at GWT. Mainly, this is java that is compiled into HTML + Ajax.

The client interface is component-oriented, and many concerns of ajax development are managed by the framework.

Unfortunately, I don't know of any equivalent in the .Net world.